# Get http headers with akka routing dsl

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I'm new to Scala, and this problem frustrates me. How can I get all headers from request?

```
val route =  {
  path("lol") {
    //get httpHeaders
    complete(HttpResponse())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have at least two options here:

a) Using `extractRequest` directive:

```
val route = {
  path("example") {
    extractRequest { request =>
      request.headers // Returns `Seq[HttpHeader]`; do anything you want here
      complete(HttpResponse())
    }
  }
}
```

b) Explicitly accessing `RequestContext`:

```
val route =  {
  path("example") { ctx =>
    ctx.request.headers // Returns `Seq[HttpHeader]`; do anything you want here
    ctx.complete(...)
  }
}
```

There's also a whole family of directives related to headers, like `headerValueByName` or `optionalHeaderValueByName`. You can find the details [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.6/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/header-directives/index.html#headerdirectives).

Comment: The `extractRequest` directive is probably the most straightforward way to get at the headers without having to manually define a route.

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn: Thanks! I've extended my answer ;)

Comment: Imho there should be `path() { get { ctx => } }` for it to compile

Comment: Why Seq and not a Map?